# Dynamic query building for report generation tool : suggestion for better approach

Tags: orm, reporting

I have a requirement for a reporting tool in which the user will be selecting the "class" that has some associated column and "filter" option in the view.

Each class is associated with a list of columns in the table and each filter condition will add some filter criteria to the "select" queries. We have a script in place that parses the input parameter to generate SQL queries but it is hard to maintain when we have to add some new column or a table to a class.

What is the best approch to write a simple and organised solution where we handle such addition or removal of coloumn or table for a reporting class.

As it's a legacy application we do not have any info about relation mapping between the tables or else we could have used ORM.

Answer (score 0):

the best solution will be `abstract query generator` in place of using ORM , where user can pass object with column , tables , condition , joins etc and `Abstract query generator` do your job.